# Novel About Shape-Shifting Aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, planets, shape-shifter

Trying to find a novel about a group of humans stranded on a planet with shapeshifting aliens.  There was another human stranded on the planet before this group arrived.  This person taught the aliens to keep a child-like humanoid shape so any other humans they met would think they were cute and wouldn't hurt them, but their real shape was something like a spider.  I think the author was fairly well-known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it.  It is *[Life Form](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/126501.Life_Form)* by Alan Dean Foster.

[image: Life Form - book cover]

> Foster presents a spellbinding odyssey of a planet miraculously like Earth. Until close observation shows that on this world, nothing is as it seems. Welcome to Xica, where nine scientists from Earth have established first contact with a humanoid civilization. Now all they have to do is live to tell about it. From the author of Greenthieves.